# Please explain jenkins lockable-resources plugin practical use

Tags: jenkins

I could not understand the purpose of the plugin, [Lockable Resources](https://plugins.jenkins.io/lockable-resources/).

In the documentation it is written that it locks resource "such as printers, phones (what!?), computers, etc"

I coudn't get what exactly it's locks and from whom? Please explain somebody on example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It prevents two jobs from attempting to use the same resource at the same time. A "resource" can be anything you want. It's identified by a name.

Consider a contrived example: You've got a Jenkins job that prints some envelopes and then some letters. If another job runs at the same time, your envelopes and letters will be mixed up. In order to prevent another job from using that printer while your job is running, you can have both jobs use a resource lock for that printer.

Or maybe you're using a pen-plotter with colour separation, so that each of the primary colours is a separate step. Your job should lock the plotter across all of the steps so that another job can't start plotting its image over the top.

You can already prevent Jenkins from running multiple instances of the same job at the same time; this is to prevent two *different* jobs from using the same resource at the same time.

Comment: So does it make sense only for such exotic use cases like plotters?
Did you have real experience with that plugin? Could it be used for 'locking' more typical kinds of resources, for example, computing resources? Like nodes or clusters or maybe threads? Or only phones and plotters?

Comment: There are several discussions in [Jenkins Users mailing list](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22lockable+resources%22+site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fgroups.google.com%2Fg%2Fjenkinsci-users&oq=%22lockable+resources%22+site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fgroups.google.com%2Fg%2Fjenkinsci-users) that deal with non-physical resources.

Comment: Operationally, if you [specify a lock](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)), that sets an environment variable that all other jobs then check and can't proceed while set.it is well planned in the [Pipeline Job example](https://plugins.jenkins.io/lockable-resources/#plugin-content-using-a-resource-in-a-pipeline-job)

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of reviving a long dead discussion .... I don't see the practical example being looked for, so let me add for posterity ....

Scenario:

- I want to deploy and test my service, in AWS, in a specific region
- Lockable resources, lets me claim exclusive use of that region for the duration of the test.  Any other runs or jobs use the same lock naming will queue up and wait their turn.
- Since that exact resource name is not pre-configured in global admin, it is created on the fly as "ephemeral", and is automatically deleted when it is not in use

Assuming my pipeline has run time parameters to select what environment i'm using and what region, I can structure a deploy and test stage of my pipeline like:

```
stage ("Deploy and test") {
     options {
         lock "my-project-aws-${params.ENV}-${params.REGION}"
     }
    
     stages {
          stage("Deploy") {...}
          stage("Test") {...}
     }
}
```